# Custom mount points in gvfs

Tags: mount, gvfs, pam

Is there a way to attach gvfs mount to a custom directory?
So instead of `~/.gvfs/sftp for leon on filezzzz.tim-online.nl/` something like: `~/mounts/filezzzz.tim-online.nl/`?

I thought about using pam_mount but that lacks the nice gnome keyring integration.

Comment: You could create symlinks in ~/mounts leading to ~/.gvfs, but I guess you want something more automatic.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'll create something with python & fuse I think.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue? :)

Comment: I'm still "experiencing" the issue. I've created a little pet project for it but I've got to finish it: https://github.com/LeonB/fusegui

Answer (score 2):

I use a symlink named "MountedFolders" which points to ".gvfs".

Since you mentioned creating something with python, you could create a python program that uses inotify to monitor ".gvfs" and creates symlinks in "~/mounts"

Comment: I have significantly slower access times to gvfs mounted files though a symlink. Its an ssh gvfs mount. I'm guessing the symlink invalidates some form of caching that makes gvfs more tolerable.